# Can I use a list to spawn enemies?

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0

I need to have about 10 enemies in my game, can I use a list to spawn them all in?

This is what I was working on but it only spawns 1 enemy in the coordinates of the last added to the list.

Here are the parts from the main game class that I am working on:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game 
{
AI enemy;

List<AI> enemies = new List<AI>();

protected override void LoadContent()
{
  Model hero = Content.Load<Model>("Assets/model");

  enemies.Add(enemy = new AI(hero, new Vector3(0, 0, -550)));
  enemies.Add(enemy = new AI(hero, new Vector3(-580, 0, -400)));
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
  {
    enemy.Update();
  }
}
}
```

Here is my AI class:

```
 public class AI
{
    public Model model;
    public Matrix world = Matrix.Identity;
    public Vector3 position;
    public Vector3 direction;
    public BoundingSphere collision;
    Matrix[] transform;

    public AI(Model m, Vector3 iPos)
    {
        model = m;
        position = iPos;
        direction = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
        transform = new Matrix[m.Bones.Count];
        m.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transform);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in m.Meshes)
        {
            collision = BoundingSphere.CreateMerged(collision, mesh.BoundingSphere);
        }
    }

    public BoundingSphere getSphere()
    {
        return collision.Transform(world);
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        world = Matrix.CreateWorld(position, direction, Vector3.Up);
    }

    public void Draw(Matrix projection, Matrix view)
    {
        Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
        model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.Projection = projection;
                effect.View = view;
                effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * world;
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

***EDIT***

I have managed to get two enemies to spawn in but only one of them goes to the correct position, I will update again when I get it fully working.

Here is the code as it stands now, I made no changes to my AI class only on my game1 class:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game 
{

List<AI> enemies = new List<AI>();

protected override void LoadContent()
{
  Model hero = Content.Load<Model>("Assets/model");

  enemies.Add(new AI(hero, new Vector3(0, 0, -550)));
  enemies.Add(new AI(hero, new Vector3(-580, 0, -400)));
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
  enemies[0].Update();
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count(); i++)
        {
            enemies[i].Draw(camera.projection, camera.view);
        }
}
}
```

Hope this helps any one and I will edit once again when I get it fully working.

***EDIT***

I have posted an answer below containing the working code.

Comment: This starts as a legitimate question, but quickly turns into "how do I fix my code?". I'm voting to close as too localized.

Comment: I am only trying to get peoples advice as I can't fix it myself and I am stuck. I didn't specifically ask for code only help with regards to my problem.

Comment: Being a beginner is fine. And asking basic questions is fine. However, make sure you ask game development related question here, and programming related questions at stackoverflow. If you find that you need to post a majority of a class, it's probably too localized. Learn to use the debugger. Read up on the [FAQ]. The way you're asking your question, the only way to answer it is to point out what you're doing wrong in your code. Because of course the answer to "Can I use a list to spawn enemies?" is "Yes". Other than that, you just have a "fix my code" question.

Comment: I got two enemies spawning now, but only 1 spawns in the correct position. I will edit my original post to show anyone else that stumbles upon this thread what to do.

Comment: If you have an answer to your question, you post it as an answer. Don't update the question with an answer.

Comment: It is not fully answered yet though, I will do that once I have it fully working :)

Comment: Your question has 3/5 votes to be closed so far. You can delete the question and get your lost rep back if you want. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

```
enemies.Add(enemy = new AI(hero, new Vector3(0, 0, -550)));
enemies.Add(enemy = new AI(hero, new Vector3(-580, 0, -400)));
```

Now imagine if I wrote the same thing like this:

```
enemy = new AI(hero, new Vector3(0, 0, -550));
enemies.Add(enemy);
enemy = new AI(hero, new Vector3(-580, 0, -400));
enemies.Add(enemy);
```

See your problem?

You're setting `enemy` to a new enemy. Then you're adding it to the list. Then you're ***changing*** `enemy` to make **another** new enemy, and adding it to the list again.

Now you have two of the same object in the list. Try this:

```
enemies.Add(new AI(hero, new Vector3(0, 0, -550)));
enemies.Add(new AI(hero, new Vector3(-580, 0, -400)));
```

Then, your `for` loop is nonsense. You're just updating the same enemy every time.

Then you can iterate over all your enemies like this:

```
foreach(AI enemy in enemies) {
    enemy.update();
}
```

Comment: Doing it that way means that it wont update the way that I currently have it. It needs to run enemy.update(); for it to be drawn but by not creating an enemy it has no value. I hope I explained that correctly

Comment: That foreach does the same, it only spawns in the last one that was inputted to the list.

Comment: @RonnieB555 I think you need to take a look at some basic programming tutorials again. Learn a bit more about control flow. Specifically how loops work, and what objects are. Your issues are very basic programming issues. They don't have anything to do with game development.

Comment: Sorry I should have stated that I am a student and still learning, I am not very familiar with this and was just looking for some general help with regards to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your update method you are calling Update() on enemy.  Now I don't know the syntax of C#, but you need something like enemies[i].Update()

Comment: When I tried this it only spawns in one enemy, using the coordinates from the last one inputted into the list.

Comment: This did end up helping thanks for the answer :) I would upvote you but I don't have the rights to since creating this thread :(

Answer (score -2):

Ok I got it working, I was forgetting to update for every enemy.

Here is the final code:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game 
 {

   List<AI> enemies = new List<AI>();

   protected override void LoadContent()
    {
     Model hero = Content.Load<Model>("Assets/model");

     //ADD MORE ENEMIES HERE
     enemies.Add(new AI(hero, new Vector3(0, 0, -550)));
     enemies.Add(new AI(hero, new Vector3(-580, 0, -400)));
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
     //HERE UPDATE FOR EVERY NEW ENEMY
     enemies[0].Update();
     enemies[1].Update();
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count(); i++)
      {
        enemies[i].Draw(camera.projection, camera.view);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: thats what vince said already. im sure this answer will be real useful if anyone wrote exactly the same code as you

Comment: Yes it was very helpful but initially it didn't fit with what I had, I would upvote him if I could but since creating this thread I have lost the ability to do so :(

Comment: A simpler way of updating each enemy without calling each one is doing this:    foreach(AI newAi in enemies) { newAi.Update(); }